# What's the error in my answer : $h(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)} \colon (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0 \colon (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let:
$$h(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)} \colon (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0 \colon (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

I was trying to answer this question: “Is the function continuous at the point $(0,0)$?” and these are my answers :

put :$\begin{cases}x=r\cos(\theta) \\ y=r\sin(\theta)\end{cases}$

**Therfore:**
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}=\lim_{r\to0} \frac{\cos(\theta)\ln(1+r^3\cos^3(\theta))}{r^2\sin(\theta)}=0$$
so the function $h(x,y)$ is continuos the point $(0,0)$

**But using wolfram alpha**
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}$$ does not exist

What is the error in evaluating the limit **I appreciate your interest and thanks for your help every time, this site is really helpful**

Comment: what happens to the ratio along the curve $y = x^3  \; \; ? \; \; $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This step

$$\ldots=\lim_{r\to0} \frac{\cos(\theta)\ln(1+r^3\cos^3(\theta))}{r^2\sin(\theta)}=0$$

is not correct, indeed it is true that $\ln(1+r^3\cos^3(\theta)) \to 0$ but we also have that the denominator goes to zero (i.e. the limit is in the form $\frac 0 0$).

As already noticed the limit doesn't exist. We can also remove the $\log$ as follows

$$\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3}\frac{x^4}{y(x^2+y^2)}$$

with $\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3} \to 1$ but the second factor is problematic for example using

- $x=y=t \to 0$

$$\frac{x^4}{y(x^2+y^2)}=\frac t2\to 0$$

but

- $x=t \to 0^+$ and $y=t^3$

$$\frac{x^4}{y(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{1}{t+t^5}\to \infty$$

Comment: +1 Nice work ...

Comment: Thank you very much and thank you to everyone on this site

Answer (score 1):

Consider the line $y=0$, Along this line ($X$ axis)$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}=D.N.E$$

But along the $Y $axis,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}=0$$

These two follow $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}h(x,y)=D.N.E $$
Hence$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}h(x,y)\neq h(0,0). $$

In your case how do you know $$\lim_{r\to0} \frac{\cos(\theta)\ln(1+r^3\cos^3(\theta))}{r^2\sin(\theta)}=0?$$